# How can I check a string without space in MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query in PHP:

```
DELETE FROM table1 
where filename="'.$name.'" 
and id=(select id from table2 where cat="'.$category.'")
```

The problem is that the string $name is without whitespace and the relative field in table1 have them. How can I do this control?

**SOLVED**

I solved it with MySQL replace() function. Trim() function didn't work.

Comment: Question nor intentions are comprehensible. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: also an example of what you have in `$name` and what the values in the database actually look like would be great

Comment: What is "without space"? Without allocation space, storing space, the character "whitespace"...? Please, elaborate.

Comment: According to the answers given, some people are better at deciphering questions than others.

Comment: @klaar ... or desperately try to guess what OP means for some rep, which is not constructive since they can never come back, OP never edit its question and it becomes useless to future users.

Comment: @AlanMachado: Agreed, this kind of rubbish questions that show a lack of effort aren't very useful ot anyone else.

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right. I mean whitespace and, for give you an example, the var $name is "filename" but the relative field in table is "file name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TRIM() :

```
DELETE FROM table1 where TRIM(filename) = "'.$name.'" and id = (select id from table2 where cat="'.$category.'")'
```

**MySQL TRIM :** http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php

Answer (score 2):

You can trim column values by using trim function .

```
DELETE FROM table1 where TRIM(filename) ="'.$name.'" and id=(select id from table2 where cat="'.$category.'")
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php